# Error during reading an image using skimage

Tags: python, anaconda, scikit-image, data-augmentation

I have been trying to read a bunch of images from a specific path , the code I am using is ~

```
images = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]

num_generated_files = 0
while num_generated_files <= num_files_desired:
# random image from the folder
image_path = random.choice(images)
# read image as an two dimensional array of pixels
image_to_transform = sk.io.imread(image_path)
```

when I am trying with a single image its working fine but when I am using the image path to pick up a random image it is showing

```
 File "C:\Users\subhr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 182, in get_reader
 "Could not find a format to read the specified file " "in mode %r" % mode
  ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your pasted code, the indentation is wrong (the loop won't work). Nonetheless, try printing the filename - you've probably come across a file which is not an image, but say a text or docx file.

Comment: Hey @VBB Thank you so much for pointing out , there were some web pages inside the folder. Also why do you say the loop wont work? Can you please explain?

Comment: Try using `imagelist = glob("*.png")` and maybe `imagelist.extend(glob("*.jpg"))`

Comment: python needs indentation for loops - your code as pasted here does not have any indentation.

Answer (score 0):

How many images are in this folder and what is their format (png, jpg, etc.)? It looks like on of the images has a unknown type (e.g. a non-image file?).

Comment: Hello @gtancev , there are a total of 132 images and it has a mixed format ( Png and JPEG and JPG) but as VBB pointed out there were some non image file